# How to manage when Squid server crash and Internet share for all when bypass server by WCCP Cisco router accrued?

Tags: cisco, router, squid

We have about 735 clients with Windows 98 SE and Windows XP (joined to domain) Windows 7 and 8 and etc. and have about 35 servers and internet connections and cache servers that one of them is Squid beside Router (CISCO) and related protocol is [WCCP](https://web.archive.org/web/20170609014938/http://www.crypt.gen.nz:80/papers/cisco_squid_wccp.html) is enabled.

[image: WCCP enabled on Router Cisco and squid]
<sub>(source: [crypt.gen.nz](http://www.crypt.gen.nz/images/wccp_protected_proxies.png))</sub>

Because Squid often crashes, I configured in Cisco that when Squid inaccessible automatically  internet connected to my network and bypass squid.

Is there any way to configure that when my server crashed this server restart automatically?  Or any other ways to resolve this problem?

Comment: The Squid proxy sends a WCCP packet to the router every 10 seconds to tell the router that the proxy is alive and ready to receive web requests http://www.crypt.gen.nz/papers/cisco_squid_wccp.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just restart squid? e.g. using [nagios](http://www.nagios.org/) or [daemontools](http://cr.yp.to/daemontools.html).

Comment: thanks alot . i read them and i will learn them but please describe for me more .im Curious to know more about what feature of these tools manage better my server? first is better or second? or another solution that you may know about it

Comment: Daemontools just manages a running process while nagios provides a scheduling engine and reporting framework.

Comment: search your description and .. find this blog .. thanks.  http://www.linuxplanet.org/blogs/?cat=5170 are there any other keywords for helping me? like this! summarized! about nagios?